# How to concat 2 expressions in interpolate

Tags: angularjs

I have directive where I want to render a list from various objects.

Controller:

```
$scope.propertyName = 'price';
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj">
 <a>{{ 'item.' + propertyName }}</a>
</div>
```

Objects `obj` will have various properties and I can't use static property name.

`{{ 'item.' + propertyName }}` return string `'item.price'` - I want expression like `{{ item.price }}`.

Comment: i think this is a bad way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would do in JavaScript:

```
{{ item[propertyName] }}
```